# PHP undefined offset array

Tags: php, arrays, undefined, offset

I'm trying to use and array to print out the first three letters of a months name (I know I can do this with date(), but I'm learning arrays in PHP and this seemed easiest).
Every time I run the code at the bottom I receive the error code below.

*Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\Documents and Settings\Garry\My Documents\Dropbox\htdocs\Web-Apps\Locander2\Alpha\step2.php on line 17*

I only get this issue if I type 8 or 9 into the index part of `$monthArray[]`.

```
<?php

$monthArray = array(01 => "Jan",
                    02 => "Feb",
                    03 => "Mar",
                    04 => "Apr",
                    05 => "May",
                    06 => "Jun",
                    07 => "Jul",
                    08 => "Aug",
                    09 => "Sep",
                    10 => "Oct",
                    11 => "Nov",
                    12 => "Dec"
                    );

    echo $monthArray[8];

?>
```

Comment: remove 0 or call as echo $monthArray[08];

Comment: Did you try with every number? :)

Comment: To all of you `echo $monthArray[08];` answers, please try your code out before posting. This will echo "Sep" and not "Aug". He is doing something wrong by using 0 in his array keys. Explain to him why he shouldn't rather that blurting out something you didn't even take time to test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$monthArray = array(1 => "Jan",
                    2 => "Feb",
                    3 => "Mar",
                    4 => "Apr",
                    5 => "May",
                    6 => "Jun",
                    7 => "Jul",
                    8 => "Aug",
                    9 => "Sep",
                    10 => "Oct",
                    11 => "Nov",
                    12 => "Dec"
                    );
```

Remove zero(`0`) at index between 1-9. Because 01 or 02 is not a valid decimal number.

Comment: @JeremyD Because the index is abbreviated to 8, not left as '08' the way he has done it.

Comment: It worked because PHP will interpret integers with leading 0 as octal. Everything is ok for 01-07 because they're the same in decimal and octal.

Comment: Explain why it would be better to remove the leading 0 instead of referencing the index [08].  (Hint: mixed indices)

Comment: Cheers everyone it worked. I thought I'd tried that, but I must of missed the CTRL+S when I tried it. Also thanks for your addition Elon Than, I couldn't see why some weren't working while others weren't.

Answer (score 5):

Prepending 0 before a number means PHP parses it as an octal value in the same way that prepending 0x causes it to be parsed as a hexadecimal value. Remove the zero, and it will work fine.

```
echo 07; // prints 7
echo 010; // prints 8
```

This is mostly used when specifying unix permissions:

```
chmod("myfile", 0660);
```

Except for that it's rarely something that you'd want to do.

This is described in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php).

```
<?php

$monthArray = array(
                    00 => "Jan",
                    01 => "Jan",
                    02 => "Feb",
                    03 => "Mar",
                    04 => "Apr",
                    05 => "May",
                    06 => "Jun",
                    07 => "Jul",
                    08 => "Aug",
                    09 => "Sep",
                    10 => "Oct",
                    11 => "Nov",
                    12 => "Dec"
                    );

    echo $monthArray[0];
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($monthArray);

?>
```

Output :

```
Sep

array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Sep"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Jan"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "Feb"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "Mar"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "Apr"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "May"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "Jun"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "Jul"
  [10]=>
  string(3) "Oct"
  [11]=>
  string(3) "Nov"
  [12]=>
  string(3) "Dec"
}
```

**As 08 and  09 are converted into octal . their value are getting placed at the 
$monthArray[00] value in the array**

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
echo $monthArray['08'];
```

or
    echo $monthArray[08];

it seems like the key you use is different

Answer (score 0):

This is a key-value array, so you need to access the key 08 instead of 8:

This works:

```
echo $monthArray[08];
```

Comment: No. This will echo Sep and not Aug.

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right. I forgot that 0x-numbers are treated as octal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Write `echo $monthArray[08];` instead of `echo $monthArray[8];`